# How to get network ip address via windows command prompt?

Tags: networking, command-line, ipv4

How to get network ip address via windows command prompt? I know tat ipconfig /all shows ip configuration, but what about having just ipv4 adress?

Comment: Maybe this would do for you: `netsh interface ip show address "Ethernet" | findstr "IP Address"` . Substitute "Ethernet" with your main adapter name

Comment: what about a more general command? I mean getting all ipv addresses?

Comment: Just don't type the adapter's name and it'll output all the IP addresses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a proper ip4 command out of similar frustration.

[ip4](https://github.com/Treer/ip4)

([.exe is here](https://github.com/Treer/ip4/releases/latest))

Comment: if you use chocolatey you can just type `choco install ip4`

Comment: I downloaded it and my antivirus is flagging it.

Comment: I reported the false flag to avast, and they claim to have fixed it

Comment: I will give it another try. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 11):

You can view all the configured IP addresses using this command:

`netsh interface ip show address | findstr "IP Address"`

You can also add the adapter name to get IP address of a specific network interface.

`netsh interface ip show address "Ethernet" | findstr "IP Address"`

This should work in at least latest versions of Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Another valid way is via WMIC:

```
wmic NICCONFIG WHERE IPEnabled=true GET IPAddress
```

This will show the IP address if there is one and the adapter that has it configured is enabled. Quite useful in many situations.

Comment: Getting the IP for the enabled adapter is a bonus!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm just building off of @Ashtray's answer,
but for me I needed **the actual IP address only**, so I'll share that here in case anyone else needs to similarly get just the address:

1. Find the name of the interface you want to know about
   For me, it was `Configuration for interface "Wi-Fi"`,
   so for me the name is `Wi-Fi`.
   Replace `Wi-Fi` in the command below with your interface name
2. PowerShell:

   ```
   netsh interface ip show address "Wi-Fi" `
     | where { $_ -match "IP Address"} `
     | %{ $_ -replace "^.*IP Address:\W*", ""}
   ```

   Output: `192.168.1.10`
3. Or, my edge case, executing command in WSL2:

   ```bsh
   netsh.exe interface ip show address "Wi-Fi" \
      | grep 'IP Address' \
      | sed -r 's/^.*IP Address:\W*//'

   # e.g.
   export REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=$(netsh.exe interface ip show address "Wi-Fi" \
      | grep 'IP Address' \
      | sed -r 's/^.*IP Address:\W*//')
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I had the same edge case with with WSL2. I noticed that `netsh.exe` returns Windows-style newlines, while `grep` and `sed` expect Unix-style newlines. This causes problems explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35605692/923560 . I fixed this issue by adding `dos2unix` into the pipe. Here is an example on how to set `$DISPLAY` (e.g. `1.2.3.4:0`, also notice the adaption for German locale):
`export DISPLAY="$(netsh.exe interface ip show config name='Ethernet 2' | dos2unix | grep 'IP-Adresse' | sed -r 's/^.*IP-Adresse:\W*//'):0"`

Answer (score 0):

For those on Windows 10 with powershell, you can run:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()) | select AddressList
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command

```
ipconfig | findstr /r /c:"IPv4"
```

it will display only IPv4 like this

**IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 169.168.81.1** -> just example

or you can use also this

```
ipconfig /all | findstr /r /c:"IPv4"
```